# Unable to set up palm rejection

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad

I am a first-time Linux user running Xubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Latitude 3189 laptop. No matter what I do, I can't get palm rejection to work.

If I run the command xinput this is the output I get:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 04F3:303A Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser    id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Things I have tried so far after some online searches:

The following commands:

```
syndaemon -i .2 -K -R -d -t

xinput set-prop 12 "Synaptics Palm Dimensions" 3, 3

xinput set-prop 12 "Synaptics Palm Detection" 1
```

I have also tried editing the "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf" file to add a line that says:

```
Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
```

Could one of you give me some more ideas on how to get this working? Doing any sort of typing is a huge inconvenience at the moment. I am completely new to Linux, so very basic explanations are much appreciated.

Thank you!

**Edit**

I uninstalled xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and now the touchpad seems to work as expected (with palm rejection).